# Close terminal window and change icon after py loads

Tags: python, bash, macos, sh

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"

python3 start.py & disown
sleep 5
exit
```

I have two questions.

1. How can I close the terminal window after the py is open?
2. How can I change the icon oof the open py?

P.S. `exit` doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to exit the terminal once the script is executed and the disowned process should run in the background. I think you need to look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611648/exit-terminal-after-running-a-bash-script) of how to exit the terminal gracefully.

Comment: My suggestion would be to run the script like this 1) `./scriptname.sh && exit` 2) `. ./scriptname.sh`. Check the above link as they provide you with more approaches and explanations.

Comment: script can run as new process and `exit` exits script and this process, not current open terminal (which runs as different process - parent process for your script). If you put some `echo` after `exit` then it will be never executed - so it shows that `exit` works but in different way then you expect.

Comment: try `exec script.sh` it should run script and exit terminal. It should replace current process (shell in terminal) with your process (script) and when your process/script ends job then it will close terminal.  https://askubuntu.com/a/201226/177036

Comment: in script you could try `kill $PPID` - it should get `Parent Process ID` and gracefully kill it - and it should close terminal.

Comment: I removed tag `linux` and add `macos` but in question you could add more details about your system, bash and terminal. Maybe it will help to find answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about setting a custom icon on Unix, but to close the terminal without terminating the script, you can use screen.

Start the screen with

```
screen -S "name_of_screen"
```

Then run your script

```
./bash_script.sh
```

Then disconnect from the terminal by doing CONTROL+A then CONTROL+D
You can now close the terminal window without stopping the script from executing.

For insight on starting a screen from within a bash script, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382137/detach-from-screen-session-inside-bash-script).

Comment: thanks, i disconnect it with disown, i need to close it thru script because of other users

Comment: @jackl `disown` only disconnects it from bash's job management, not from the terminal device.

Comment: but i can manually close the terminal window without closing my script.

Answer (score 0):

Script can run as new process and `exit` exits script and this process, not current process in terminal (bash) which runs as parent process for your script.

If you put some `echo` after `exit` then it will never display it - so it shows that `exit` works but in different way then you expect.

---

In bash you can try to run

```
exec script.sh
```

and it should replace current process in terminal (bash) with your process (script) and when script will exit then it should close terminal.

---

In script you can try to get `Parent Process ID` and  (gracefully) kill it

```
kill $PPID
```

---

You can search more on similar portal `Ask Ubuntu`

[Is there a command to close a terminal window via commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19397/is-there-a-command-to-close-a-terminal-window-via-commandline)

Comment: this didnt work, i forgot to mention this is on MacOS

Comment: @jackl there is portal similar to `AskUbuntu` but for MacOS: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). Maybe they will have idea how to do it on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run a script in the background you can simply create a service
see this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-launchd-to-run-services-in-macos-b972ed1e352)

about the icon does your py has a gui if so consider compiling it to an excutable and add an icon to it .
you can do so with pyinstaller :

```sh
pyinstaller --windowed -i youricon.icns GWF_CS.py
```

for more info see pyinstaller [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)